# MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". first parameter to `mongoose.connect()`ion()` is a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongoose, dotenv

[image: Index.js file]

[image: This is the error i am getting]

[image: This is my dotenv file]

I am making an api using express js and  i have used mongo db as a database . When i am connecting mongo db with the help of that string using dotenv file i am getting this error
i dont know why. please help me with this i am totally beginner with this.

[image: package.json]

Comment: try without quotes and spaces `MONGO_URI=blablabla`

Comment: no same problem. when i log the mongo_url in my index.js file it is saying undefined

Comment: Can you you show your `package.json`?

Comment: i have added package.json file ss in question

Comment: process.env.any variable is giving me undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was creating .env file in src directory but it should be created in your root directory.
[image: env file]